# I have a page that uses a mysql connection. How can i make 1 mysql request using a new connection without messing up the current connection?

Tags: php

I currently have a page that is something like this

```
<?php
mysql_connect(...);

mysql_query('the pages queries');

### here ###

mysql_query('the pages queries');

?>
```

but where it says ### here ###, i basically want to do this:

```
mysql_connect(new server/new user)
mysql_query(update db2.log ...)
```

is there any easy way to do this so it 100% won't mess up any thing else on the site? I want to log stuff on a lot of sites, so want to put a little function in (then call it) on loads of different sites of mine. currently i'm using curl to request a page (basically http://mysite.com/log/log.php?vars=x&here=y)

Answer (score 4):

Use link identifiers.

```
$link = mysql_connect(blablabla);
$link2 = mysql_connect(blablabla2);

mysql_query('SQL QUERY 1', $link);
mysql_qurty('SQL QUERY 2', $link2);
```

Comment: yeah, that's the way you should do, every time... also if you use 1 single connection...

Comment: what if i don't have a link identifier on the initial one?

also, does wordpress do this by default?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. If it is, you'll have to use link identifiers for both. OR better yet, use MySQLi class instead of old mysql_ functions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want to throw the link identifier in every other query. In that case, use `mysqli` or `PDO` with `PDO_MySQL` if available to avoid messing up the 'last mysql resource identifier', after which you close that connection / destory that instance.